# What is the difference between ActiveMQ and Apache Camel

Tags: apache, activemq-classic, esb

Both are open source ESB. So what are distinct features each of them have and in which scenarios/usecases, each should be used?

Answer (score 0):

- `Apache camel` is basically a Mediation engine which will help you to define
  mediation and routing rules for your application,
- whereas `Activemq` is a message broker that allows you to
  send messages between producers and consumers using Java Messaging System (JMS)

Apache Camel can use ActiveMQ for forwarding of messages.

Both are altogether different types of systems, with different functionalities, and can not be compared

hope this helps!

---

Good luck!